# Variable Memory addressing

Tags: memory, relative-addressing

Using NASM
I have:
VAR DW 0000
memptr: times 1024 DB 0H

I want to use VAR as a pointer into the block of memory memptr

1. How do I load VAR with the address of memptr + 1023 ?
2. MOV [VAR] , EAX ; Correct me here, this moves the content of EAX into the memory location
   pointed to by VAR or into VAR ?

Tried nearly everything I can thing of.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: VAR1 DW 0000
I'm trying to understand the difference when you use VAR1 and [VAR1]
eg. MOV EAX, DWORD VAR1
 ; Is the address of VAR1 loaded or the value stored there?
IF :  MOV [VAR1], DWORD VAR1+2 
; What is going on here?  What is being incremented?